# What are some good Intel XDK alternatives?

Tags: cordova, editor, intel, intel-xdk

With Intel [changing the focus of their Intel XDK Editor and deprecating lots of important features like their ondevice debugger](https://software.intel.com/en-us/forums/intel-xdk/topic/705276), what are some good free alternatives to develop cordova/phonegap apps?

Features this editor should have:

- Plugin management like the Intel XDK
- Build settings and Build export (apk and ipa)
- Play Store Publish tools
- Certificate support allowing to create f.e. Apple .p12 directly
- Support for ios, android AND windows 10

Comment: Please see the release notes for recommended alternate tools > https://software.intel.com/en-us/xdk/docs/release-notes-information-intel-xdk <

Comment: From what I can tell, these are alternatives to the deprecated XDK features, not to the editor. I understand that Intel is not going to do publicity for other editors, but the solutions provided mostly appear like complicated (and not ideal) workarounds.

Comment: The editor used inside the Intel XDK is the open source Brackets editor. You can download and install it here > http://brackets.io/ < and, in fact, you can use it to edit your XDK project files directly. The other recommendations, in the release notes are, in most cases, the very tools upon which those deprecated features are based on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I develop cordova application more then year, I did it by Visual Studio 2015, WebStorm and Xcode. And I suppose you need to make a choice:

- As far as I know only Xcode (https://developer.apple.com/xcode/) has App Store Publish tools
- Support for ios, android AND windows 10 -> only WebStorm
- Good plugin management -> Visual Studio 2015
- Build settings and Build export (not ipa) -> Visual Studio

I like VS2015, by the way for building cordova applications you can use build.phonegap.com